# Accessibility narrator reading the model class name instead of grid content of WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, accessibility, jaws-screen-reader, narrator

In my WPF application, there is a grid view with three columns as Name, City, and Country. Please see the model class:

```
public class Employee
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string City{ get; set; }
    public string Country{ get; set; }
}
```

I have added the grid UI like the below code:

```
<Grid>
      <ListView x:Name="DisplayEmployee">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView AllowsColumnReorder="False">
                    <GridViewColumn Width="300" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Name, Mode=OneWay}">
                        <GridViewColumnHeader Content="{Binding LabelName}"/>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn Width="150" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=City, Mode=OneWay}">
                        <GridViewColumnHeader Content="{Binding LabelCity}"/>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn Width="150" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Country, Mode=OneWay}">
                        <GridViewColumnHeader Content="{Binding LabelStatus}"/>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>                
      </ListView>
 </Grid>
```

The issue is that, when we try to read the grid content using the ZOOM or JAWS accessibility tool, it is reading the corresponding class name `Employee` instead of the grid content.

When I updated the `Employee` class like the one below, it is reading properly;

```
public class Employee
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string City{ get; set; }
    public string Country{ get; set; }
    public override string ToString()
    {
         return Name + " " + City + " " + Country;
    }
}
```

But I cannot use the string concatenation here. Is there any way to fix this issue by updating the UI element? Any help would be appreciable!

Comment: Have you tried setting `AutomationProperties.HelpText=""`? I have never used those tools so I don't know which properties are being read.

Comment: @XAMIMAX Yes, I tried this. But not fixed

Comment: It would help if you updated your question with that suggestion so we can see where you tried that option. Thanks

Comment: I have added the  AutomationProperties.HelpText="" on the GridViewColumn tag

Comment: Have you tried specifying the content of your gridviewcolumn header and applying the AutomationProperties to that control? I don't think gridviewcolumn is the correct place. And your changes are not showing in your question.